# How to specify default MTA?

Tags: email, crontab, mta

I'm trying to use the MAILTO function in crontab on my mybookworld (it's a NAS)

I've installed a rather unfamiliar (i think) MTA: ESMPT

With mutt (console based email client) it works perfectly. But in crontab there is no reaction (even if I'm using the same crontab file as on my desktop machine with postfix as MTA). So think maybe the system doesn't know that ESMTP is a MTA that could be used from crontab.

How can I tell crontab what MTA to use?

Answer (score 1):

Both Vixie-cron and `dcron` use the MTA at hardcoded location **`/usr/sbin/sendmail`**<sup>1</sup>. Make sure this points to `esmtp`.

Also, you may need to configure the relay destination system-wide, in `/etc/esmtprc`, in order to receive output from system cronjobs (`/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.*/`). This is not necessary if you only use your own crontab.

<sup>1</sup> (Some other programs may be using `/usr/lib/sendmail`.)

Comment: thanks for the try, but symbolic links to /usr/sbin/sendmail, /usr/bin/sendmail and /usr/lib/sendmail don't work for me:(

Comment: @Captn: Could you elaborate on *what* exactly are you linking to *where*? (To clarify, running `namei -l /usr/sbin/sendmail` should point to ESMTP, and it must be readable and executable.)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing "ssmtp", it's really easy. Just point it at another MTA like your ISP's. Look for "ssmtp.conf".

Sometimes /etc/sendmail is a link to the default MTA if that's what is more of interest.

Comment: Unfortunately ssmtp is not in http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/cs05q1armel/cross/unstable/ |   link to /etc/sendmail don't work, too.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up my Linux flavours a bit there. In qmail on Gentoo there's this symbolic link to boost qmail's sendmail compatibilities: /usr/sbin/sendmail -> /var/qmail/bin/sendmail

Comment: Here's a link to a SSMTP tutorial. If you can install it and have another mail box to point at (like your ISP's) it'll take two minutes to get running (if you're testing from the command line also install "mailx" or "mail" and type something like "mailx -s "Testing 1,2,3" me@me.com < /dev/null". http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/132006